# How to join with null value?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

This code returns only posts having a rating. How I can get all posts with null value where the post does not have a rating?

```sql
select 
    posts.id, 
    posts.user_id, 
    posts.name, 
    posts.created_at,
    ratings.post_id,
    ratings.avg,
    ratings.count
from 
    posts
join (
    select
        post_id,
        avg(rating) as avg, 
        count(rating) as count
    from 
        ratings
    group by 
        ratings.post_id
) ratings
on ratings.post_id = posts.id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will keep all the rows from the 'left' side of the `join` statement (`posts` table) that do not have a correponding row on the 'right' side of the statement (`ratings` table). The missing rows from the 'right' side will be filled with `NULL`S.